JWT token in ASP.NET Core - bearer error="invalid_token"
When I use the login endpoint, a token is generated. However, when I attempt to access an endpoint that requires authorization, I receive a "401 Unauthorized" error.
The issue does not seem to be with the request itself, as I have tested it with Postman and am including the access token in the header.
Can anyone help me identify the problem?
This is the code in my program.cs :
builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("MyAllowSpecificOrigins",
                builder =>
                    {
                        builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200")
                               .AllowAnyHeader()
                               .AllowAnyMethod();
                    });
        });
      
builder.Services
       .AddIdentityApiEndpoints<PessoaComAcesso>()
       .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ListaDeTarefasContext>();
    
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
       {
           options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
           options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
       })
       // .......
    .AddJwtBearer(options =>
        {
            options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                    {
                        ValidateIssuer = true,
                        ValidateAudience = true,
                        ValidateLifetime = true,
                        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                        ValidIssuer = builder.Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
                        ValidAudience = builder.Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
                        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(builder.Configuration["Jwt:Key"]))
                    };
        });

builder.Services.AddAuthorization();

builder.Services.AddHealthChecks();

c.AddSecurityDefinition("Bearer", new OpenApiSecurityScheme
     {
         In = ParameterLocation.Header,
         Description = "Por favor insira o token JWT com o prefixo 'Bearer '",
         Name = "Authorization",
         Type = SecuritySchemeType.ApiKey,
         BearerFormat = "JWT",
         Scheme = "Bearer"
     });

c.AddSecurityRequirement(new OpenApiSecurityRequirement {
    {
        new OpenApiSecurityScheme
        {
            Reference = new OpenApiReference
            {
                Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme,
                Id = "Bearer"
            }
        },
        new string[] { }
    }});
});

app.UseCors("MyAllowSpecificOrigins");app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

The group of endpoints:
 var groupBuilder = app.MapGroup("tarefas").RequireAuthorization().WithTags("Tarefas");

app.settings.json:
"Jwt": {
    "Issuer": "https://localhost:7086",
    "Key": "my-key"
}

Is there anything in my configuration that could be causing the 401 Unauthorized error? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

The swagger configuration should be :
Type = SecuritySchemeType.Http


http – for Basic, Bearer and other HTTP authentications schemes
apiKey – for API keys and cookie authentication

Reference : https://swagger.io/docs/specification/authentication/
